# Check if index of iteration is divisible by 2

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know I can check this with pure Js `index % 2 === 0` however when
I'm attempting to use it in React which should work I get errors from linter:

```
<div className="columns">
      {posts.map((item,index) => (
        <>
          <div className="column is-half">
            <Card {...item} />
          </div>
          {index % 2 === 0 && </div><div className="columns">}
        </>
      ))}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

**Edit:**

```
<div className="columns">
{posts.map((item,index) => (
      <div className="column is-half">
        <Card {...item} />
      </div>
      {index % 2 === 0 && (
        </div><div className="columns">
    )}
  ))}
```

The above still throws syntax error. I've checked brackets and logic is correct too.

Comment: `</div><div className="columns">` this is invalid JSX

Comment: Provide the error details

Comment: It's throwing syntax error pointing at the line with the divisibly by 2 logic.

Comment: @Mark By the way of how interpreters/compilers work, syntax error location is famously inaccurate in all languages...

Answer (score 1):

I think you have invalid JSX syntax and this is your issue.
You cannot open a `div` element without setting the closing tag directly or setting the closing tag in a loop. This is invalid syntax, even if it would fit from the logic...

Try this:

```
<div className="columns">
    {
          posts.map((item,index) => (
            <>
                <div className="column is-half">
                    <Card {...item} />
                </div>
                {
                    index % 2 === 0 && 
                    <div className="columns">
                    </div>
                }
            </>
        ))
    }
</div>
```

Comment: While you are correct, the question seems to be about a linting error. Without that we're left guessing

Comment: The problem I see is that `<div className="columns">
                    </div>` within the logic. It throws syntax error even though the logic itself is correct. I want to close the `columns` tag **before** I start another one.

Comment: Yes, I know, what you are trying to achieve. But this way it will not work. I think you have to rethink your logic (maybe you can achieve this via `css`). Maybe you can provide some more information, what `class="columns"` is exactly for. Do you want to create a new line after 2 columns? Maybe you can provide your `css` class codes as well.